# Is it possible to merge objects in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, object

Is it possible to merge two objects together? For instance:

If you had 2 objects

```
    Dim returnOptionObject1 As OptionObject
    returnOptionObject1 = New OptionObject

    Dim returnOptionObject2 As OptionObject
    returnOptionObject2 = New OptionObject
```

Then set their values

```
    returnOptionObject1.EntityID = OptionObject.EntityID
    returnOptionObject1.OptionId = OptionObject.OptionId
    returnOptionObject2.SystemCode = SystemCode
    returnOptionObject2.Facility = OptionObject.Facility
```

Could you somehow combine these objects into one new object as in

```
    Dim newObject As OptionObject = returnOptionObject1 + returnOptionObject1
```

Comment: I would rather create another class which contains the common or all possible attributes of both objects.

Comment: Well you pretty much would have to create another class to do this.  On top of that you will need to overload the "+" operator, or simply create a whole new merge function

Comment: Seems like your need to *merge* the objects has arisen in trying to solve some different problem. it would be better if you post the original problem and lets us see how that could be solved in *Object Oriented* way. Getting a way to merge these two objects will **NOT** solve your original problem, it would make it worse. I would try to avoid such deliberate efforts until i am sure there is no good way out.

Comment: Probably a good idea, I think I'm probably going about it the wrong way. I made a new post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18496533/procedure-overwriting-itself-every-time-it-is-called

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no inherent language support for such an operation.  It will require some level of object specific code in order to get it to work.  If you truly want to use `+` to do the merging you can define an overloaded operator on `OptionObject` and implement the merge logic there.

```
Class OptionObject
  Public Shared Operator +(left as OptionObject, right as OptionObject) As OptionObject
    ' Insert merge logic here 
  End Operator  
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you would have to either overload the "+" operator, or create a whole new function.  The function would have to dictate how the objects are merged(deciding what property values are used for the new object, etc).

You could also create a whole new class for your new merged objects, but you still are going to have to either overload the "+" operator or create your own merge function.

Answer (score 0):

You could also overload the New constructor and pass each object to it.  Filter out the unique default value of the properties not being used by each object and set the properties of the new object

```
    Dim returnOptionObject1 As New OptionObject
    Dim returnOptionObject2 As New OptionObject

    returnOptionObject1.EntityID = 1
    returnOptionObject1.OptionId = 2
    returnOptionObject2.SystemCode = 3
    returnOptionObject2.Facility = 4

    Dim newObject As New OptionObject(returnOptionObject1, returnOptionObject2)

Class OptionObject
    Property EntityID As Integer = 999
    Property OptionId As Integer = 999
    Property SystemCode As Integer = 999
    Property Facility As Integer = 999
    Public Sub New()

    End Sub
    Public Sub New(obj1 As OptionObject, obj2 As OptionObject)
        If obj1.EntityID <> 999 Then
            Me.EntityID = obj1.EntityID
        End If
        If obj1.OptionId <> 999 Then
            Me.OptionId = obj1.OptionId
        End If
        If obj1.SystemCode <> 999 Then
            Me.SystemCode = obj1.SystemCode
        End If
        If obj1.Facility <> 999 Then
            Me.Facility = obj1.Facility
        End If
        If obj2.EntityID <> 999 Then
            Me.EntityID = obj2.EntityID
        End If
        If obj2.OptionId <> 999 Then
            Me.OptionId = obj2.OptionId
        End If
        If obj2.SystemCode <> 999 Then
            Me.SystemCode = obj2.SystemCode
        End If
        If obj2.Facility <> 999 Then
            Me.Facility = obj2.Facility
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```